# How to select insert more than once using INSERT INTO?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert two data each for each field in table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, 'custom', custom
SELECT post_id, '_custom', 'field_514e91e73640d'
FROM `wp_temp`
WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
```

However, this doesn't work. Is there anyway to achieve this in one query in MySQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, 'custom', custom FROM `wp_temp` WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT post_id, '_custom', 'field_514e91e73640d' FROM `wp_temp` WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a separate `FROM` and `WHERE` clause with each `SELECT`, but it's possible with UNION or UNION ALL.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, 'custom', custom
FROM `wp_temp`
WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT post_id, '_custom', 'field_514e91e73640d'
FROM `wp_temp`
WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes with a `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, '_custom', 'field_514e91e73640d'
FROM `wp_temp`
WHERE custom IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT post_id, 'custom', custom
FROM `wp_temp`
WHERE custom IS NOT NULL
```